# How do I fix poor sleeping habits?

Tags: sleeping

Ever since I started university, my bed time has become later and later to the point that 3-4am is my norm.

As I am about to be on university break, is there an easy way to restore my sleeping habits to normal (around 10-11 pm).

Answer (score 2):

I find staying up for 30-35 hours will help reset my body clock. I would not sleep one night then go to sleep a few hours before the time I want to reset my sleep time to. This then allows me to wake at a normal time and then sleep at a normal time again